Salesforce functions replacement for appexchange packages?
Has anyone building appexchange packages (esp. for regulated industries) used Salesforce functions and what are they migrating to with the EOL imminent?
I have an appexchange package where functions would be a great fit. We need to process large CSVs and complex SOAP callouts that would hit Apex governor limits.
The recommended migration path to Heroku is unsatisfying for a few reasons:

No simple way to package Heroku app
Doesn't operate within the trust boundary
Someone needs to operate/maintain the Heroku instances on an ongoing basis
Heroku platform has been in maintenance-only mode for years. Might as well consider AWS lambda or other alternatives if going the off-platform route.


Heroku platform has been in maintenance-only mode for years. Might as well consider AWS lambda or other alternatives if going the off-platform route - sounds like you've answered your own question.

BTW, functions were never actually packagable in themselves. They had a lot of promise, but we simply could not adopt them without a whole load of extras, including packagability and the provision of package protected function containers. We have, instead, continued with using packagable components and the clever use of problem domain decomposition and "async" processing. Note that DataWeave should help with some of your data transformation needs in a much more efficient manner than straight Apex.

You might want to use some middleware - MuleSoft is of course Salesforce's offering these days.

@PhilW - Yes, mulesoft is def an option. The main issue is that both sides of the API are large financial institutions so for compliance reasons either SF subscriber or client we are building the app for would need to operate the integration. Having a "native" solution where they can just pay SF and there isn't anything to manage would be a huge plus.
